# Nginx doesn't allow a global location directive

Tags: nginx, server-configuration

I want to configure a location directive that is inherited by all server blocks.

In Apache, if I use the Alias directive outside the Virtualhost block, it applies to all virtualhosts, each host can access the location provided.

In Nginx, when I put the location directive outside a server block, it says "location directive is not allowed here".

Is there a better solution than re-defining the location in each server block?

Comment: What problem do you want to solve? Usually there is no reason to want different servers to have the same location directive.

Comment: I have a common software that I want all domains to use.

A common example is phpmyadmin. Every Linux distribution packages it with a global "Alias" directive for Apache.

Comment: I worked around it. I wrote the Location directive to a global.conf.inc file and wrote an include in every server block. That way, whatever location directive I put in global.conf.inc is defined in all server blocks.

However, better suggestions are still welcome.

Comment: @DorukFisek did you ever manage this, without relying on explicitly including a block? I am looking for a way to ensure that all virtual hosts do not allow access to .htaccess or .git files, by default, reducing the risk of mis-configuration.